# Breaking up an infinite-dimensional optimization problem into a sequence of finite-dimensional problems

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

My question is a bit vague. I have an infinite-dimensional convex optimization problem and I can solve constrained versions of the problem by restricting the domain of the objective function to a finite-dimensional convex subset. These are, however, only very thin (far from dense) subsets of the original infinite-dimensional domain and they are very different from each other. So I am thinking about the solving first the constrained problem on one of the finite-dimensional subsets $V_1$, leading to an optimizer $p_1$, then constructing a new finite-dimensional subset $V_2$ that contains $p_1$, but is different from $V_1$. Then I solve the problem on $V_2$, leading to an optimizer $p_2$ and construct a new set from $p_2$. In this way, I want to break up the infinite-dimensional problem into a sequence of finite-dimensional problems on sort-of-orthogonal subspaces. My question is if a similar strategy is known for other problems and already has been investigated.

Comment: Doesn't this approach go under the name "Galerkin methods"?

Comment: I am not sure how this is related to Galerkin methods. Can you give a reference?

Comment: Generally speaking, in a Galerkin method you choose a sequence of increasing finite dimensional subspaces, solve the problem over the subspaces and let the dimension go to infinity. Not sure, if your spaces $V_j$ are increasing, though. If you choose the spaces not increasing, this goes more in the direction of (block) coordinate descent methods (where the subspace would be spanned by a bunch of standard basis vectors).

Comment: My subspaces are not increasing. I think that what I have in mind goes more in the direction of coordiate descent methods. Thank you!